# 2 fact tables, 1 dimension table connected to a date table - relationships issues

Tags: powerbi-desktop, measure

I am quite new to this and have spent some time trying to solve it by myself but it doesn't seem that I am doing this right.

It seems quite simple in theory though.

I have 2 tables connected to my Staff members table as well as a Date table. I am trying to calculate the "Handling time" and "Productivity" per Staff member. Not sure if that has an importance but note that the key used to connected individuals between both fact table is not the same but both are matched with the Staff member.

Time filters are from the Date table.

The key between date table and fact tables is Year_Week.

The result for the processing time equals to the full years of that individual with no aggregation. Is there any way I could land that weekly breakdown.

One hint for me was to use the USERELATIONSHIP field but I can't seem to make it work either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FYzO.png)

I tried to make relationships one-to-many, no change.